# Designing the structure of a NinJump-like game using J2Me

Tags: java-me

I'm trying to create a [NinJump](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bfs.ninjump&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5iZnMubmluanVtcCJd)-like game using J2ME, and I've run into some problems with the animation.

My game built this way:

- A thread is started as soon as the game is started. A while loop runs infinitely with a 20ms delay using thread.sleep().
- The walls constantly go down - each time the main while loop runs, the walls are animated.
- The ninja is animated using a TimerTask with a 30ms interval.
- Each time the player jumps, the player sprite is hidden, and another sprite appears, which performs the jump using a TimerTask: 20ms interval, each time the task is executed the sprite advances the its next frame and it also moves (2px each time).

The problem is that when the player jumps, the wall animation suddenly gets slow. Also, the jumping animation is not smooth, and I just can't seem to be able to fix it using different animation time intervals.

I guess there's something wrong in the way I implemented it. How can the problems I mentioned above?

Comment: post a snippet of your code that you think relates to the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `TimerTask` to animate the sprites, do it on the main game loop.

Comment: How would I have different animation run in different speeds then?

Comment: Have your loop sleep at every 10ms. Use int counters to know when to call nextFrame.